# If $\int_0^T f_n(t) \to 0$ then does$f_{n_k}(t) \to 0$ a.e for a subsequence?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_n$ be a sequence with $f_n(t) \geq 0$ for all $n$ and $t$.

If $\int_0^T f_n(t) \to 0$  then does it follow that $f_{n_k}(t) \to 0$ a.e for a subsequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_0^T f_n(t)\rightarrow 0$ means that the sequence $f_n$ converges to 0 in $L^1$. From a well-known theorem of measure theory this implies convergence in measure to the zero function, and this , in turn implies that there exists a subsequence of $f_n$ , say $f_{n_k}$ which converges to 0 a.e.

The proof of the first assertion is easy:

$\mu(\{x:|f_n(x)-0|\geq \varepsilon\})=\int_{\{x:|f_n(x)|\geq \varepsilon\}}d
\mu\leq \int_{\{x:|f_n(x)|\geq \varepsilon\}} \dfrac {f_n(x)}{\varepsilon}d
\mu \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon }\int_0^T f_n(x)d\mu\longrightarrow 0$.

Therefore $f_n$ converges to zero in measure.

The proof of the second assertion is in every book of real analysis (e.g. check Folland)